# Generate fat arrow function property assignment in ts-morph

Tags: typescript, code-generation, ts-morph

I want to generate code like this using ts-morph.

```
const obj = {
   func: (arg: number) => 3
}
```

I have the `ObjectLiteralExpression` already and need to add it. I'm guessing through `addProperty` or `addPropertyAssignment`, but I cannot figure out how to pass it an arrow function for the assignment.